# Fragment передача view

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Имеется много фрагментов, для примера возьму *test* и *test2*.
Вызвал *test*, в котором имеется `ListView`, по нажатию на который открывается окно добавления *item* (`fragmentadd`), но перед показом `fragmentadd`, я во фрагменте *test* всем `View`-элементам выставляю `enadled = false` - т.е. они стали не активны.

В `fragmentadd` ввел имя и нажал `OK` - так теперь же нужно назад разблокировать все элементы фрагмента *test*. Разблокировал, как по нажатию на кнопку *OK*, я получил фрагмент:

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getString("test));
```

получил его `View` и установил уже `enadled = true`, но к фрагменту `fragmentadd` обращаются и другие фрагменты - их 20 штук.  Не могу же я в холостую искать 20 других фрагментов, при том, что активный один?

Хотел через `setArguments()` передать либо фрагмент, либо его `getView()`, но не получилось.

Подскажите, как мне во фрагмент передать на него ссылку или его `getView()`?

Comment: Т.е. вы из всех 20 фрагментов вызываете один фрагмент и хотите в запускающем фрагменте отловить событие возвращение на него? Если да, то вам нужны setTergetFragment и onActivityResult

Comment: Мне нужно в том одном фрагменте иметь ссылку на View вызывающего фрагмента.

Comment: Это порочная практика если вам надо на самом деле менять состояние по событию показа/скрытия фрагмента. Вам надо именно эти события отлавливать. Один фрагмент не должен ничего знать о другом. Тем более иметь ссылку на его разметку. Это-источник сонмища проблем

Comment: Просто нужно из второго фрагмента получить доступ к view из первого.

Comment: Оба фрагмента одновременно отображаются на экране? Если нет, то вся ваша затея обречена на провал и мучения. И зачем нужно блокировать View в фрагменте?

Comment: Оба отображаются.Иначе зачем мне делать неактивным другой фрагмент.Почему то onActivityResult постоянно java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: что за `getView()` фрагмента? вы не путаете фрагмент с адаптером списка `ListView`

Comment: Нет после указания разметки ее можно получить этим способом.Я же так делаю неактивными элементы все в первом фрагменте.А теперь нужно из второво сделать активными в первом

Answer (score 1):

Всё ещё не очень понятно зачем вам блокировать/разблокировать что-то. Пока запущен фрагмент Б вы не можете нажать на что-то в А фрагменте не закрыв Б. Это если фрагмент Б - диалог. Если не диалог - то таки в момент запуска Б блокируйте интерфейс в А, а после закрытия Б, отловив это событие способ описанным в первом комменте разблокируйте А. Методы блокировки/разблокировки можете реализовать в базовом абстрактном фрагменте и унаследовать все остальные фрагменты типа А от него. Так у вас и код дублироваться не будет и проблем с прокидыванием ссылок на View не будет

Comment: Если фрагмент Б меньше по размеру фрагмента А то я могу нажать на фрагмент А при активном Б.Я и пытаюсь заблокировать view в момент запуска Б.В первом коменте так и делаю только получаю искючение.Пока я сделал функцию статик код не дублирую.Идея такая теперь. После закрытия Б передать в а что нибудь в А отловить onActivityResult и уже разблокировать.Но почему то исключение и все.Мол нуль getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, null); говорит и все.Что не так?

Comment: @Ivan, покажите код и точную строку падения. Наверное вы что-то где-то указать забыли

Comment: Так и есть не дописал.Ошибка была в setTargetFragment.Я вызывал setTargetFragment(this,1); анужно было test2.setTargetFragment(this,1);Мне лучше функцию по блокировке использовать как статик или Методы блокировки/разблокировки можете реализовать в базовом абстрактном фрагменте и унаследовать все остальные фрагменты типа А от него?Просто я создам класс со статик функциями.Туда еще штук 20 войдут.Не все же во фрагмент пихать?

Comment: @Ivan, я бы так сделал - в базовом фрагменте переопределил бы `onActivityResult` в коем бы включал вьюхи. А в  Б сделал бы статический метод запуска этого фрагмента с  А в виде аргумента. В нём можно вызвать отключение вьюх у А и установление целевого для Б фрагмента

Comment: Мне кажется трудно так будет.У меня функция которая ищет все вьюхи и если нашла то отключила.

Comment: @Ivan, зато так будет правильней. А метод ваш вы вполне можете использовать просто вызывайте его в `onActivityResult`

Comment: Наверное создам фрагмент в котором буду хранить нужные функции для работы приложения.потом все фрагменты унаследую от него.думаю так пойдет.